# Infopath form publishing issue

Tags: deployment, sharepoint-2010, infopath2010

I designed the infopath form. I am writing required programming code on button clicked event. But while publishing the infopath form i am getting[image] error; Please observe:  It should allow me to select "Form Library" option so that i can do. From Microsoft it is suggested from [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/922125) that i need to remove code. but everything is required in my form. I need to deploy form with code. without code it is without any value.

I have associate tryst certificate as well as my form is with full trust. 
My infopath services are configured properly. 
I am running sharepoint2010 in 2-tier farm.
I am using Infopath 2010 with Sharepoint 2010.
What else i need to be added...?

If i removes code then it shows me [image] and deployed properly.
Please , give me right direction.

```
    **Edited:** 
    I deployed this form as form template and activated it by central admin site. and assigned to form library as content type. but while running this form (from Document-> New Document->MyContentTypeTemplate),

 i got exception:

        Business logic failed due to an exception. 
        (User: domainname\user, Form Name: MHPMEmployeeInformationTemplateChanged9, IP: ,    Request: http://spwfe1:7000/_layouts/FormServer.aspx?

    XsnLocation=http://spwfe1:7000/FormServerTemplates/MHPMEmployeeInformationTemplateChanged9.xsn&SaveLocation=http:

    //spwfe1:7000/OfficialResumeFormLibrary&Source=http://spwfe1:7000/OfficialResumeFormLibrary/Forms/AllItems.aspx&DefaultItemOpen=1, Form ID: urn:schemas-microsoft-com:

    office:infopath:MHPMEmployeeInformationTemplateChanged9:-myXSD-2011-09-06T18-40-25, Type: UnauthorizedAccessException, Exception Message: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005.)    a2e8bb5f-26d2-485a-bf9c-0a333eaa71e7


        Verbose     Calling GlobalStorage.SetItem with index LastExceptionLogged value type UnauthorizedAccessException.    a2e8bb5f-26d2-485a-bf9c-0a333eaa71e7


        Medium      Exception thrown from business logic event listener: System.UnauthorizedAccessException:

 Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005.

     at EmployeeInformation_Template.DocGenerator.CreateWordDocument(Resume objResume, Object oTemplate)     

at EmployeeInformation_Template.FormCode.GetInfopathData()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c__DisplayClass4.<RunWithElevatedPrivileges>b__2()   

  at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)    

 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback secureCode, Object param)     at 


Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)     at Employe...   a2e8bb5f-26d2-485a-bf9c-0a333eaa71e7
```

Why should This? : I wondered When Microsoft is avoiding to use Interop COM Objects to use for word file automation which i used in my infopath form. [Look Here](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q257757#kb2)

What i have to do now? do i need to go with alternatives ? or move by trying to resolve the issues ??? Please , i need right direction.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. As soon as you have code in your form, your only option is to deploy as "Administrator approved Form".

To get the form to show in your library, do the following:

- Upload it in the Central Administration (General Applications
  Settings -> Manage Form Templates)
- activate the according Feature In the "Advanced Settings" section of
  your library
- allow "ContentType Management"
- Add the Form as ContentType

Comment: do you mean that, the form that has custom code, events, that we cannot deploy as from library template?

Comment: Yes indeed, it has to go through "administrator approval" due to potential security risks. A bit stupid if you ask me, because how can an admin know if a form is a potential risk or not, unless he reverse engineers the code, which not many admins can do. However you can add the form as content type to your library.

Comment: really wondering, foolish production by Microsoft. isn't it ? but the infopath for that i have, I had deployed as content type as well. but again wondering why any action is not performing on button click. even not executing when assigned to infopath webpart... why should that ?

Comment: well, in large companies it does make sense... You need to set your form to "Full Trust" in Form Options -> Security and Trust